# How can I make a windows media player control's URL truly null?

Tags: c#, winforms, metadata, axwindowsmediaplayer

I am trying to modify my track's metadata, but I can't because the file I try to edit is constantly in use. I believe this is because my `axwindowsmediaplayer` control is still reading from the file. I want it to stop reading from the file so I can edit it, but it seems I can't make its URL property equivalent to nothing- it wants to keep the same URL if I tell it to set the URL to null or `" "`. If I give it an invalid URL though, it errors. How can I make it so its URL is *actually* null or better yet, make it so it stops reading from my file altogether?

```
 private void editTrackMetadataToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form metaform = new MetaData();
        metaform.Show();
        Properties.Settings.Default.StopMedia = true;
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = null;//ahahahahahahaha
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562399(v=vs.85).aspx), it is possible to release the current resource with the `close` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
   axWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentPlaylist.clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

For folks who are still looking for answers:

1. close method does not work, it stops the player but you can still click the
   play button to play the old one.
2. axWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentPlaylist.clear(); works as a charm.